# Table rate shipping is not working

Tags: shipping, table-rates

Here is the shipping rules.

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
DNK,*,*,0.0000,79.0000
NOR,*,*,0.0000,300.0000
SWE,*,*,0.0000,200.0000
```

I've disabled Flat-rate shipping and free shipping by navigating to: Configuration -> Shipping methods.

Also changed the default method in One page checkout settings.

But still the website it not taking the table-rate shipping and the shipping price is not calculating according to the rules.

Also it shows shipping amount as 79 all the time, I've edited DNK amount to 80 but it still shows 79 (only table-rate shipping is enabled).

[image]

Disabled all cart pricing rules, still it is now working.

I've spend around day to find this, is there someone can give some suggestions/idea about how this issue is happened?

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked for the error log? is it showing any error? when you do the checkout what is it showing? please add more details if possible with Screen Shots

Comment: It is showing shipping amount as 0.00 and when I pay the purchase is completed without adding the shipping amount. Is this a common issue? There is no error in the log.

Comment: is there any promotional rules applied on the cart which allows free shipping. Please check for the shopping cart price rules...

Comment: I hope you are selecting country denmark, norway or sweden in the shipping address.

Comment: @Dexter I'm checking if there is any cart rules are overwriting this.

Comment: @Kalpesh Yes, I'm doing that all the time.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Please do reindexing and try again.. Moreover please recheck the price you imported for DNK

Answer (score 5):

Please follow these steps to resolve:

1) Check that the shipping_tablerate table is populated with same data as you expect (and in correct columns)

2) Check that the condition for those rows in shipping_tablerate matches the condition you want (i.e. price condition). If it is say imported as weight condition then you need to re-upload

3) Put a new csv file in with just 1 global rule and check that works

4) If all else fails put a Mage::log() to output the sql and then verify it

Its going to be a configuration issue/misunderstanding.

Comment: Shipping cost estimation working on cart page but not working on the checkout page, what is the error?